# Convert VCHAR to TIMESTAMP or DATE in Teradata

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, teradata

I uploaded a table using fastload and want to convert the event_time column to a timestamp or just get the dates since I don't need the time component.

The text format is 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM', for example, '05/24/2013 08:12:00 AM'

I have tried

```
CAST(event_time AS TIMESTAMP(0))
```

and

```
CAST(SUBSTRING (event_time,1,10) AS date)
```

but they don't work for me. The error I get is invalid timestamp/date.

As a bonus question,
I don't think there are any outliers in the data (i.e. every row is in format as described above), but if there were, how do I account for those errors? or will Teradata automatically pass on those rows?

Answer (score 2):

The CASTs don't work because this is not the default timestamp/date format.

The easiest way utilizes the TO_DATE function which is supported since TD14:

```
TO_DATE(event_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM')
```

Before TD14 it's:

```
CAST(CAST(event_time AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYbHH:MI:SSbT') AS DATE)
```

Regarding outliers, they will result in an "invalid date/timestamp" error. When you cast them during FastLoad to a Timestamp those rows will fail to load and will be inserted into the ET-error table. But you can't use the newer CAST-syntax in FL, must be the old Teradata-style cast:

```
:event_time (TIMESTAMP, FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYbHH:MI:SSbT')
```